# How to remove hidden HTML from Radactor editor in CrafCMS 3

Tags: redactor, editor

I am using Redactor 1.0.1 plugin in Craft 3, When copy/paste from any website into WYSISWG boxes, hidden HTML is included. How do I remove that?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for you, you can activate/use the [source](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/source/) plugin to switch the view. That way no html is generated when you paste something

Maybe [this](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/paste/#setting-pastePlainText) option can help you too. There is also a [paste](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/paste/#callback-paste) callback you can use to change the inserted html

Comment: I already checked above options, and I have used Radactor default field, so if I have to apply Paste callback or Paste settings then where do I have to write?